# mysql query - only select where id = id from another table and a field in that table = a value

Tags: php, mysql

my title may not explain what I am looking for, this is my current query for pulling in products for a shop:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Items 
             WHERE ((Items.menu_id='$menu_id' AND Items.status='1') 
                   $colour_sql) 
             $order_sql 
             LIMIT $lim_from,$limit_per_page");
```

The part where it says $colour_sql I want to have somthing that says:

```
AND (Items.id=colour.product_id AND colour.colour='pink')
```

So it only show products that are pink, with the colours being in a seperate table. I have searched for answers, but I can't seem to find one explaining my situation, maybe its because I don't know exactly what i'm, looking for, any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to join with table `colour` you need to do either a join or a subselect.

**Join**

```
$menu_id = mysql_real_escape_string($menu_id);
mysql_query = "SELECT i.* 
  FROM items i
  INNER JOIN colour c ON (c.product_id = i.id)
  WHERE i.menu_id = '$menu_id' 
    AND i.status = '1'
    AND c.colour = 'pink'
  ORDER BY .....
  LIMIT {intval($limit_per_page)} OFFSET {intval($lim_from)} ";
```

**Subselect**

```
$menu_id = mysql_real_escape_string($menu_id);
mysql_query = "SELECT i.* 
  FROM items i
  WHERE i.menu_id = '$menu_id' 
    AND i.status = '1'
    AND i.id IN (SELECT c.product_id FROM colour c WHERE c.colour = 'pink')
  ORDER BY .....
  LIMIT {intval($limit_per_page)} OFFSET {intval($lim_from)} ";
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe an inner join?

```
[...]
FROM Items
INNER JOIN colour
ON colour.id = Items.colour_id
WHERE [blablabla]
AND colour.colour = 'pink'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the colour table to your query:

```
FROM Items,colour
```

or

```
From Items INNER JOIN colour ON Items.id = colour.product_id
```

But I observed that you have the product_id in your colour table. Why don't you do the reverse in the Items table you add the colour id.

Comment: The products can have more than one colour, so I couldnt do it like that, if I understand you correctly

Comment: It was just an observation :)